# golang use channel with time out pattern to jump out of loop

Tags: go

Learning from go time out pattern [go concurrency patterns](http://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and), I try to check a channel and to break out of a for loop

```
Loop: 
   for {
      //do something repeatedly very fast in the for loop

     //check exitMessage to see whether to break out or not
      select {
          case <- exitMessage:
               break Loop
          case <- time.After(1 * time.Millisecond):
       }
   }
```

The time-out avoids `select` gets stuck reading from a channel. The problem is that on a Windows XP machine, that delay is much longer than 1 millisecond (per [time delay inaccuracy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847533/interrupt-pattern-for-google-go-goroutine-speed-issue)) which slows down the for-loop significantly.

A hacked-up solution is to get another goroutine (I know it's cheap) to listen for the `exitMessage`

```
exitFlag := 0

//another goroutine to check exitMessage
go fun(in chan int){
    exitFlag = <-in
}(exitMessage)


for exitFlag == 0 {
       //do something repeatedly very fast in the for loop


 }
```

Is there a better pattern to interrupt a for-loop in go?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about using a [select statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) with a default clause which will execute if the channel can't receive?

```
Loop:
   for {
      select {
          //check exitMessage to see whether to break out or not
          case <- exitMessage:
               break Loop
          //do something repeatedly very fast in the for loop
          default:
               // stuff
       }
   }
```